# Check if array values are ascending or descending

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, sorting, for-loop

I need to loop over the values of an array and tell if the array values are ascending, descending, or neither. This is what I have currently, but I cant figure out what I am doing wrong?

I have seen a different method to solve this, but I'm sure I am going in the right direction and since I'm learning I want to keep pursuing with my current logic. Thanks!

```
function ascDscArray(array) {
    for (var i=1; i < array.length-1; i++) {
        if (array[i-1] < array[i]) return "yes, ascending";
        if (array[i-1] > array[i]) return "yes, descending";
        else return "no";
    }
}
```

Note: Here are two example arrays that I am trying to test with `[15, 7, 3, -8]`, and `[4, 2, 30]`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! When you call `return`, the loop finishes running, and no further logic occurs. As such, you'll only `return` output for the **first** `i`. If you want multiple outputs, you'll need to use something like `console.log()` instead of `return`. If you want to know if the entire array is ascending / descending, I'd recommend making use of flags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a check for two elements in advance and select a comparison function and check all elements with [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every). This allows to use a short circuit if a previous element and the actual element does not match the expected order.

Then return the type of the order or the message, that the array is not ordered.

```js
function check(array) {
    var direction = array[0] < array[1]
            ? { type: 'asc', fn: (a, b) => a < b }
            : { type: 'desc', fn: (a, b) => a > b };

    return array.every((v, i, a) => !i || direction.fn(a[i - 1], v))
        ? direction.type
        : 'no';
}

console.log([[15, 7, 3, -8], [4, 2, 30], [1, 2, 3]].map(check));
```

A version, which uses the given code and compairs the first element with all following elements. For storing the direction two variables are used and beeing updated in conditions.

Later check if both variables are `true`, then return `'no'` or the direction.

Disadvantage: It iterates all elements

```js
function ascDscArray(array) {
    var asc = false, desc = false;
    for (var i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[0] < array[i]) {
            asc = true;
        }
        if (array[0] > array[i]) {
            desc = true;
        }      
    }
    if (asc && desc) return 'no';
    return asc ? 'asc' : 'desc';
}

console.log([[15, 7, 3, -8], [4, 2, 30], [1, 2, 3]].map(ascDscArray));
```